# 2D Array - Select range of columns

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a 2D numpy array `A` (MxN) and want to select a range of columns, lets say from m to n, (or rows - does not matter) like this:

```
A = A[m-n,:]
```

Is there a way to simply achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it as:

```
B = A[m:n,:]
```

or if you want to include the n-th row:

```
B = A[m:n+1,:]
```

Similarly for columns:

```
C = A[:,m:n]
```

or

```
C = A[:,m:n+1]
```